# How to update TeXstudio and Texlive 2021?

Tags: texlive, texstudio, miktex-update, update, texlive-2020

since I did not find recently solution (only questions that are asked few years ago) I want to ask again.
When I opened TeXstudio today it told me there is a new version to download.
My questions are:

1. How do I update TexLive? I know that there are liveupdates for MikTex, is there something similar to Texlive?
2. How to update TeXstudio without getting all settings lost that I made so far?

It would be nice to get a full answer, since there are surely lots of other noobs like me that have the same questions :)

Thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: The first question is answered in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/82917). BTW, TeXlive 2021 doesn't exist yet. As far as the second question is concerned: why do you think an update make you lose settings? I regularly update TeXStudio and never had problems.

Comment: @campa Thank you very much!! Maybe I should ask: How do you update TeXstudio?

Comment: Hey @ZPlaya, just download the latest version from [here](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) and install it, no need to save setting etc. I have never done that, just when moving to new hardware or for reinstalling Win10. This works perfect for Win10, but it should also for other OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

TeXLive versions can live in separate installs, so one can install TexLive 2021 next to TexLive 2020, if so desired.

According to the official page, TeXLive 2021 will be released on [April 6, 2021 (page snapshot)](https://archive.is/wip/nlZF4)

```
Plan for TeX Live 2021:
15feb: candidate/final sources committed, test builds begin.
25feb: tlpretest starts, CTAN updates continue there and in tlnet.
10mar: code freeze for final build, major bug fixes only.
22mar: final updates from CTAN, final doc tweaks.
23mar: deliver TL image for TeX Collection packaging/testing.
2apr: deliver TeX Collection DVD image for manufacturing.
6apr: public release (also of MacTeX).
June?: delivery of DVDs to members.
```

Since you are mentioning MikTex I am assuming you are on Windows platform.

An easy way to install and keep TeXStudio upgraded is via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), with:

```
choco install texstudio
```

and

```
choco upgrade texstudio
```

Comment: TL21 is available today.